# xterm not using .Xresources

Tags: shell-script, xinit

I've one .xinitrc with the following lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources &
xset r rate 200 30 &
xterm & #fixme: xterm is not reading loaded .Xresources
exec /etc/alternatives/x-window-manager
```

Why the xterm is not using the settings loaded with the `xrdb`?

**P.S.: this xterm inside .xinitrc does not use the settings loaded from xresources, but once the wm is running it works right.**

I don't remember how to fix it (has been years that I don't play with linux).

Comment: Dont use `&` at the end of the xrdb command. It needs to finish before running xterm.

Comment: oh... so simple... -.- @meuh if you want you can answer that I'll mark your answer as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources &
xset r rate 200 30 &
xterm & #fixme: xterm is not reading loaded .Xresources
exec /etc/alternatives/x-window-manager
```

the line with `xterm` needs to run in the background, using "&" because the window manager has to run to manage the `xterm` (and if `xterm` were not put in the background, it would block the script from proceeding to invoke the window manager). The `xrdb` and `xset` commands *both* should complete before starting other programs, because they will complete (and exit) rapidly, and because they initialize things for you:

- [`xrdb`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/xrdb-1.html) sets up resource values in the root window which can be read by `xterm`, and
- [`xset`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/xset-1.html#scrolltoc) (less important) is changing the key repeat rate.

Further reading:

- [About X: Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/general/aboutx.html)
- [7) How do I set resources?](https://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/general/aboutx.html#7)
- [14) What is the precedence for resource files?](https://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/general/aboutx.html#14)

Answer (score 0):

I use Atom to compile and run C programs and it outputs to xterm - I found this link when looking to enlarge the xterm font in a permanent way. These posts really helped me get a handle on xterm -

https://askubuntu.com/questions/161652/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-of-xterm